# How to configure mapDispatchToProps with react redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

**Below is my container code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { fetchMovies } from './actions';

export class Container extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchMovies();
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    movies: state.movies,
  };
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    fetchMovies: bindActionCreators({fetchMovies}, dispatch),
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Container);
```

**Action:**

```
export const fetchMovies = () => dispatch => {
  console.log('fetchMovies called');
  // const movieResponse = fetchAPI(apiUrl);
  // console.log('movieResponse => ', JSON.stringify(movieResponse));
  dispatch({ type: actionTypes.FETCH_MOVIES, payload: [] });
};
```

**Store:**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../rootReducer';

const middlewares = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
);

export default store;
```

**Dependency Versions:**

```
"prop-types": "^15.7.2",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-flexbox-grid": "^2.1.2",
"react-redux": "^7.1.0",
"react-router": "^5.0.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
"react-scripts": "3.0.1",
"redux": "^4.0.4",
"redux-actions": "^2.6.5",
"redux-promise-middleware": "^6.1.1",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
```

> **Getting error:**
>
> `TypeError: this.props.fetchMovies is not a function`

I am using latest react version of 16.8. Is that the reason? or am i missing something in configuration?

Comment: Try this `fetchMovies: bindActionCreators(fetchMovies, dispatch),`

Comment: I had the same code and updated to object later, no luck :(

Comment: IIRC bindActionCreators wraps the function with dispatch, so your are dispatching it 2 times. Try:
export const fetchMovies = () => {
  return { type: actionTypes.FETCH_MOVIES, payload: [] };
};

Comment: the second param is dispatch only and i dont think i am doing anything wrong in the actions

Comment: any alternate answers plz?

Comment: could you update your question with `rootReducer` file code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is much more simple.**

I don't know why you are using "thunk", I would suggest "saga" instead. I don't like the idea of adding some logic (fetching) to the actions, but any way here is your solution.

**Container:**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import connect from "./connect";

export class MovieList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchMovies();
  }

  render() {
    const { isFetching, movies } = this.props;
    const toLi = (movie, key) => <li key={key}>{movie.title}</li>;

    return isFetching
      ? <span>Data is loading</span>
      : <ul>{movies.map(toLi)}</ul>
  }
}

export default connect(MovieList); // pay attention to this
```

Binding container with store, this way will keep your container much like component:

```js
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchMovies } from "../actions";

const props = state => ({
  movies: state.movies,
  isFetching: state.isFetching
});

const actions = {
  fetchMovies
};

export default connect(
  props,
  actions
);
```

**Actions file:**

```js
export const FETCH_MOVIES = `MOVIE/FETCH_MOVIES`;
export const FETCHED_MOVIES = `MOVIE/FETCHED_MOVIES`;
export const FETCH_ERROR = `MOVIE/FETCH_ERROR`;

export const receivedMovies = movies => ({
  type: FETCHED_MOVIES,
  movies
});

export const onError = error => ({
  type: FETCH_ERROR,
  error
});

export const fetchMovies = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({type: FETCH_MOVIES})

  return fetch(API_URL)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => dispatch(receivedMovies(data)))
    .catch(err => dispatch(onError(err)));
}
```

A full working demo is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/7h56r

Comment: ,Thanks for the demo. Is this example with Saga or without? How to use saga?

Comment: I dont want to disappoint anyone who tried to answer, hence +1 vote from my side. But my problem ill have to figure out still after comparing with the demo link provided

Comment: contact to me (check my profile) I will try to explain how to use saga.

Answer (score 1):

You are using bindActionCreators wrong. It takes an object as the first argument. The properties of the object are the action creators themselves.

And returns an object just like mapDispatchToProps does.

This might work

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchMovies }, dispatch)
}
```

Or you might not use bindActionCreators at all

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  fetchMovies: () => fetchMovies(dispatch)
}
```

Comment: I even tried with that as well, still the same issue

Comment: I have updated answer with the complete code for mapDispatchForProps

Comment: sorry to say, no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight mismatch when using the bindActionCreators function. Try like this

```
const matchDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({
    fetchMovies
}, dispatch)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use mapDispatchToProps i do it directly and it works perfectly

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchMovies }
)(Container);
```

Comment: I tried this too, but still no luck :( In component did mount if i use this.props.fetchMovies(), it throws the same error. I am wondering if its the problem by using the latest react version?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it two ways

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  fetchMovies: () => dispatch(fetchMovies())
})
```

or

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  fetchMovies: bindActionCreators(fetchMovies, dispatch)
})
```

Also, make sure you're importing the connected `Container`

```
import Container from './container'
```

instead of

```
import { Container } from './container'
```

From further look into your code, your actions is not a pure function, hence it led to another error. Here's a quick sample [fix](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-redux-playground-b9fuo) for your code

Comment: Need working code, have tried all these, but unfortunately not working.

Comment: This should work, unless you're not importing the connected `Container`. Can you show me how you use your `Container`? It should be `import Container from ...` instead of `import {Container} from ...`

Comment: Its in the posted question, can u refer the question

Comment: No it is not. I'm asking how you USE your `Container`. I.e: Your `app.js` that does `<Container>..</Container>`

Comment: `import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './reduxStore/redux.store';
import { Container } from './container';

window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
global.jQuery = $;

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Container />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;`

Comment: Right, you're not importing the redux connected `Container`, and won't have any props from `redux`. Check my updated answer

Comment: I am extremely sorry to say, still its the same error

Comment: If you can provide an working react-redux link example connecting with hooks, that be great. Ill see the difference and correct it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call it like this:

`this.props.actions.fetchMovies()`

You may also need to update your mapDispatchToProps method. We call ours like such:

```
const actions = {
 fetchMovies: fetchMoviesActionFunction, // or whatever your function is called here
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch) });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go another way. It's been a while since I worked with thunk last time, but I did not use `mapDispatchToProps` alike methods. See if this approach does the trick for you

```
export class Container extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchMovies());
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    movies: state.movies,
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(Container);
```